# Stored proc to get list of tables and stored procs using those tables from all databases

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

A single stored proc which do the following work: when I pass a column name, I should get a list of all the tables containing that column, and a list of all stored procedures that are using those tables from all databases

Comment: What have you tried? We will not write all code for you. Have you looked and tried stuff found in the information schema views? see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778(v=sql.100)

Comment: "tables using tables"? "column name"? Your question is all over the place.

Comment: /*I tried below query which can get all the tables from one data base when we give the column name and sp_depends can get the depends on the tabel or a stored proc from one database */
SELECT tab.name AS table_name,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,col.name AS column_name FROM sys.tables AS tab
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON tab.OBJECT_ID = col.OBJECT_ID
WHERE col.name LIKE '%Policy_Activity_ID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;

Comment: but I need a query or 
a stored proc which can work like, when I give the column name I need all the table containing that column and all the stored procs having that tables from all the databases

Answer (score 0):

```
  DECLARE @rolename AS VARCHAR(200) = 'testx_table'
  DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(2000) = '',
          @string2 VARCHAR(2000) = '',
          @string3 VARCHAR(2000) = '',
          @string4 VARCHAR(2000) = ''

  IF @rolename = 'testx_table'
    GOTO table_op

  IF @rolename = 'testx_proc'
    GOTO proc_op

  TABLE_OP:

  BEGIN
      DECLARE @catalog   VARCHAR(500),
              @schema    VARCHAR(50),
              @tablename VARCHAR(500),
              @tabletype VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE crs_tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT table_catalog,
               table_schema,
               table_name,
               table_type
        FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].tables
        WHERE  table_schema = 'DBO'

      OPEN crs_tables

      FETCH next FROM crs_tables INTO @catalog, @schema, @tablename,
      @tabletype

      SELECT @catalog = table_catalog,
             @schema = table_schema,
             @tablename = table_name,
             @tabletype = table_type
      FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].tables
      WHERE  table_schema = 'DBO'
             AND @catalog = table_catalog
             AND @schema = table_schema
             AND @tablename = table_name
             AND @tabletype = table_type

      SET @string1 = 'GRANT INSERT ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                     + ' TO ' + @rolename
      SET @string2 = 'GRANT DELETE ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                     + ' TO ' + @rolename
      SET @string3 = 'GRANT UPDATE ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                     + ' TO ' + @rolename
      SET @string4 = 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                     + ' TO ' + @rolename

      EXEC(@string1)

      EXEC(@string2)

      EXEC(@string3)

      EXEC(@string4)

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @catalog = table_catalog,
                   @schema = table_schema,
                   @tablename = table_name,
                   @tabletype = table_type
            FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].tables
            WHERE  table_schema = 'DBO'
                   AND @catalog = table_catalog
                   AND @schema = table_schema
                   AND @tablename = table_name
                   AND @tabletype = table_type

            FETCH next FROM crs_tables INTO @catalog, @schema, @tablename,
            @tabletype

            SET @string1 = 'GRANT INSERT ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                           + ' TO ' + @rolename
            SET @string2 = 'GRANT DELETE ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                           + ' TO ' + @rolename
            SET @string3 = 'GRANT UPDATE ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                           + ' TO ' + @rolename
            SET @string4 = 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + @tablename
                           + ' TO ' + @rolename

            EXEC(@string1)

            EXEC(@string2)

            EXEC(@string3)

            EXEC(@string4)
        END

      CLOSE crs_tables

      DEALLOCATE crs_tables

      GOTO EXIT
  END

  /* */
  PROC_OP:

  BEGIN
      DECLARE @p_catalog VARCHAR(500),
              @p_schema  VARCHAR(50),
              @p_name    VARCHAR(500),
              @p_type    VARCHAR(50),
              @xtype     VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE crs_routines CURSOR FOR
        SELECT r.specific_catalog,
               r.specific_schema,
               r.specific_name,
               r.routine_type,
               s.xtype
        FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].routines r
               INNER JOIN sysobjects s
                       ON s.NAME = r.specific_name
        --and s.xtype = 'FN'
        WHERE  r.specific_schema = 'DBO'

      OPEN crs_routines

      FETCH next FROM crs_routines INTO @p_catalog, @p_schema, @p_name,
      @p_type,
      @xtype

      SELECT @p_catalog = r.specific_catalog,
             @p_schema = r.specific_schema,
             @p_name = r.specific_name,
             @p_type = r.routine_type,
             @xtype = s.xtype
      FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].routines r
             INNER JOIN sysobjects s
                     ON s.NAME = r.specific_name
      --and s.xtype = 'FN'
      WHERE  r.specific_schema = 'DBO'
             AND @p_catalog = r.specific_catalog
             AND @p_schema = r.specific_schema
             AND @p_name = r.routine_name
             AND @p_type = r.routine_type

      SET @string1 = 'GRANT ' + CASE WHEN @p_type = 'PROCEDURE' OR @xtype =
                     'FN'
                     THEN ' EXECUTE '
                     ELSE ' SELECT' END + ' ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + '[' +
                     @p_name +
                     ']'
                     + ' TO ' + @rolename
      SET @string2 = 'GRANT ' + ' VIEW DEFINITION ' + ' ON ' + '[dbo]'
                     + '.' + '[' + @p_name + ']' + ' TO ' + @rolename

      PRINT @string1 + ' / ' + @p_type

      EXEC(@string1)

      EXEC(@string2)

      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @p_catalog = r.specific_catalog,
                   @p_schema = r.specific_schema,
                   @p_name = r.specific_name,
                   @p_type = r.routine_type,
                   @xtype = s.xtype
            FROM   [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].routines r
                   INNER JOIN sysobjects s
                           ON s.NAME = r.specific_name
            --and s.xtype = 'FN'
            WHERE  r.specific_schema = 'DBO'
                   AND @p_catalog = r.specific_catalog
                   AND @p_schema = r.specific_schema
                   AND @p_name = r.routine_name
                   AND @p_type = r.routine_type

            FETCH next FROM crs_routines INTO @p_catalog, @p_schema, @p_name
            ,
            @p_type,
            @xtype

            SET @string1 = 'GRANT ' + CASE WHEN @p_type = 'PROCEDURE' OR
                           @xtype =
                           'FN'
                           THEN ' EXECUTE '
                           ELSE ' SELECT' END + ' ON ' + '[dbo]' + '.' + '['
                           +
                           @p_name
                           +
                           ']'
                           + ' TO ' + @rolename
            SET @string2 = 'GRANT ' + ' VIEW DEFINITION ' + ' ON ' + '[dbo]'
                           + '.' + '[' + @p_name + ']' + ' TO ' + @rolename

            PRINT @string1 + ' / ' + @p_type

            PRINT @string2 + ' / ' + @p_type

            EXEC(@string1)

            EXEC(@string2)
        END

      CLOSE crs_routines

      DEALLOCATE crs_routines

      GOTO EXIT
  END
```